# Inputmask not functional, accepting invalid characters

Tags: acumatica

I have added the InputMask on the Company Name field on the Customers screen.

My Implementation(ReplaceOriginal in customizer):

```
    #region FullName    
        [PXMassMergableField]
        [PXDBString(255, IsUnicode = true, InputMask=">AAAAAAA")]
        [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Company Name", Visibility = PXUIVisibility.SelectorVisible, Enabled = false)]

        public string FullName { get; set; }
        #endregion
```

In the customer editor it appears as a MaskEdit correctly.
[image]

**Issue**

It is still accepting symbols when I've explicitly it set to only accept letters/digits. It's allowing a save and a write back to the DB record.

[image]

[image]

Any recommendations appreciated.

Comment: your code looks fine, try a IISReset to make sure the latest code is compiled

Comment: Hi Simon, Yeah i've tried restarting IIS a few times. Unfortunately it's still saving invalid characters to the DB

Comment: You might want to try with a normal PXTextEdit, see if it does any difference. The mask should still work with PXTextEdit

Comment: I figured it out. I should have known. I needed to re-create the control entirely. I made the changes without re-creating the control. Thank you for all your help Simon. I appreciate the input.

Comment: I'm glad you found your issue. I suggest accepting your answer in a few days, it could help others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it the input mask wasn't working was I didn't re-create the control after making the changes to the DAC field. Once I deleted it, re-created the control and restarted IIS it worked fine.